# Why can't electrons flow in the depletion region of a semiconductor?

Tags: electric-fields, electrons, charge, semiconductor-physics

In a semiconductor when there is a depletion region electrons can't flow through this and acts as an insulator. This depletion region can expand when a battery is plugged a certain way. Why can't charge travel through this depletion region?

My second question is when electrons enter the p-side of the semi-conductor the p-side becomes negatively charged and looses holes. Why aren't the free electrons in the n-type attracted to the negative p-side?

Comment: First, you should split this up into two separate questions, one about semiconductors, and one about batteries. Second, what do you mean by the "p-side" of a battery? How are holes involved in the operation of a battery?

Comment: Sorry, I meant "p -side of the semi conductor". The p-side is where the 'holes' are.

Comment: In your last sentence, why should electrons be attracted to negative polarization?

Comment: i think it's because, in the depletion region, there are no (or very few) free electrons or free *"holes"* (which act as positively-charged charge carriers).  in the depletion region, the outer shells of all of the silicon atoms and those of the dopants (perhaps gallium, phosphorus, arsenic) are filled (and *"satisfied"*) shells.  there your semiconductor is more of an insulator.

Comment: Maybe this will clarify it for you: Macroscopic charge  on matter,  when looked at the atomic level ( electrons and holes are at the atomic level) is the sum of microscopic charges, i.e. sum of electrons for negative and sum of holes for positive.